# next.js strange behavior regarding a simple link

Tags: next.js

Here's my page:

```
const videos = [] // a long array of more than a thousand YouTube vides codes

const View = () => {
    const randomVideo = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];

    return <a target='_blank' href={`https://youtube.com/watch?v=${randomVideo}`}>Random Video ({randomVideo})</a>
}

export default View
```

It seems that I have learnt something wrong about next.js. This page shows my the random number as the link text each time I refresh the page, but the link href does not change.

What have I learned incorrectly about next.js?

Comment: You want to use `getServerProps` and calculate the randomized number at the server level. Next won't generate a random number on page load, because the pages are pre-rendered server-side (if you're using `getStaticProps`). I can post a longer explanation as an answer if this doesn't get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you could try it this way and see how it react :

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const videos = [] // a long array of more than a thousand YouTube vides codes

const View = () => {

    const [randomVideo, setRandomVideo] = useState(videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)])

    useEffect(() => {
        // Console.log each time the randomVideo State change
        console.log(randomVideo)
    }, [randomVideo])

    // If you need to change randomVideo Value with a function
    const generateRandomVideos = () => {
        setRandomVideo(videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)])
    }
    
    return <a target='_blank' rel="noreferrer" href={`https://youtube.com/watch?v=${randomVideo}`}>Random Video
        ({randomVideo})</a>
}

export default View
```

Comment: Basically I had to calculate the random video, at client side.